# CSS - Trying to apply styling to a class within a class within a modal popup

Tags: html, css, asp.net, class

EDIT:
I have still not found a solution however i have managed to avoid the issue entirely. If someone know why this doesn't work it would be incredibly helpful so i know for the future. Thank you

-

I can't seem to get this to work and i've tried searching everywhere for an answer.

This is the gist of it (all nested within a modalPopup Panel.

```
<div class="body">                
<div>
     <div class="left">
         <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Name:" />
    </div>
     <div class="right">
         <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" Text="" />
     </div>
</div>
```

Also i should add that i can add styles to the body class with no issue.

I have tried these in CSS:

```
.modalPopup .body.left {}

.modalPopup .body .left {}

.modalPopup .body > left {}

.modalPopUp .body > .left {}
```

And the same for the right class.

Am i missing something incredibly obvious?

I can give you more code/information if needed feel free to ask away.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Here is all the Code

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="smsBatchUI.Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolKit" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<link href="modalpopup.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" Text="Pop Up" runat="server" style="display:none" />
            <ajaxToolKit:ModalPopupExtender TargetControlID="Button2" ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1"
                    CancelControlID="ButtonCancel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
            </ajaxToolKit:ModalPopupExtender>
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" style="display:normal" align="center" CssClass="modalPopup">
                <div class="header">
                    <header>
                        Batch SMS Messaging
                    </header>
                </div>
                <div class="body">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkVerify" runat="server" style="display:none" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true" /><br />

                    <div>
                        <div class="left">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Name:" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="right">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName" Text="" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <div class="left">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Number:" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="right">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNo" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <div class="left">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Message:  " />
                        </div>
                        <div class="right">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtMessage" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <div class="left">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Template: " />
                        </div>
                        <div class="right">
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" Width="200px" ID="ddlTemplate">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Select Template" Value="DefaultValue"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="HR" Value="HR"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="CT" Value="CT"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="IT" Value="IT"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <div class="left">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Send Date: " />
                        </div>
                        <div class="right">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDate" Text="YYYY-MM-DD" /><asp:Label runat="server" Text="(YYYY-MM-DD)" Font-Size="10px" />
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Preview" style="padding-top: 0px" /> 
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server"  Height="150px" Width="300px" ID="txtPreview" Text="Click Preview to see your message before you Submit it." TextMode="MultiLine" /> <br />
                </div>
                <div class="footer">
                    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Preview" ID="btnPreview" OnClientClick="Preview();" />
                    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="Validate()" /> <br />
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" /> <br /> <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="ButtonCancel" runat="server" Text="Close" />
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
body { color: #373d3f; }
.modalBackground
    {
        background-color: floralwhite;
        filter: alpha(opacity=60);
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
.modalPopup
    {
        background-color: #E8ECED;
        width: 400px;
        border:1px solid #666666;
        border-radius: 12px;
        padding:0
    }
.modalPopup .header
    {
        background-color: #014B96;
        height: 30px;
        color: White;
        line-height: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-top-left-radius: 8px;
        border-top-right-radius: 8px;
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
    }
.modalPopup .body
    {
        min-height: 50px;
        line-height: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
        display: inline-block;
    }
.modalPopup > .body > .left
    {
        width: 30%;
        float: left;
        text-align: right;
    }
.modalPopup > .body >.right
    {
        width: 65%;
        margin-left: 10px;
        float:left;
    }
.modalPopup .buttonalignleft
    {
        text-align: left;
    }
.modalPopup .footer
    {
        padding: 6px;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the modalPopup class?

Comment: The Modal Pop Up is working perfectly as is the .modalPopUp .body {} css. I can link you the entirety of the code if you need it,  i just thought i'd only post what i thought was more relevant?

Comment: did you try `.modalPopup > .body > left{}` if this is not working. Post the code.\

Comment: Updated, hope it helps :)

Comment: .modalBackground
    {
        ...
    } 
is this working?

Comment: Yes everything works as intended, besides the .modalPopup .right {} and .modalPopup .left {}

Answer (score 0):

I hope that can help.

```css
*{
margin:0;
padding: 0;

}

p{color:#fff;}
html,body{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

.modalPopup{
position:relevant;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:#fd3;
}

.modalPopup .body {
position:absolute;
width:90%;
height:90%;
background-color:#f00;
left:5%;
top:5%;
}

.modalPopup .body .left {
width:50%;
height:100%;
background-color:#0f0;
float:left;
}
.modalPopup .body .right {
width:50%;
height:100%;
background-color:#00f;
float:left;}
```

```html
<div class="modalPopup">
<div class="body">
<div class="left">
<p>Left</p>
</div>
<div class="right">
<p>Right</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: for css best practice don't use upper case char for id and class. so for class name for example you can use "modal-popup" instead of "modalPopup". don't name a class or id the same as html tag name, that might be a bit confusing

Comment: For some reason the code snippet works but as soon as i put it into my code it doesn't work

Comment: Yes it doesn't work in my application for some reason sorry.